# How to multiply generating functions with $x^n$ and $x^{5n}$ and $x^{2n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have to solve a combinatoric problem using generating functions, how to further simplify this?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n}*\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{5n}}*\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$$

Comment: Note that these are all geometric series and can be summed that way.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote + instead of *

Comment: I am sorry I found the same question was already asked I will undelete it .

Answer (score 1):

These are all [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and can be summed that way.  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac 1{1-x}\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^5)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The product is equal to 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}
$$
by using the geometric series.